# Are there any Regex patterns that can determine a shipping company by an account number?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building a form wherein the user may enter a shipping account number.  Primarily, I need to determine if the user has entered a *valid* pattern for a shipping account.

Secondarily, I would like to determine who the shipper is (e.g. UPS or FedEx).  This would be similar to the way one can run a Regex against a credit card number to determine the card type (e.g. Visa, Amex, etc).

Please note that I am looking to validate *account numbers* and not tracking numbers.

Any help is appreciated.

In Summary:

1. Primary Goal: a shallow validation for shipper *Account Number*, or
   a more definitive idea if it is even possible.
2. *Account Number* differs from Tracking Number in that it is the
   customer identifier for the shipper used for billing purposes.
3. Web searches/research result in numerous resources for Tracking Number,
   but nothing definitive about Account Number.
4. Examples: None available due to the data being flagged sensitive
   internally, and web searches being inconclusive. I compare it to
   Credit Card Numbers: There shouldn't be any examples of valid
   numbers freely available. However, in the case of Credit Cards, the
   patterns are established enough that those can be located.
5. Why I ask the community?  Just in case there is a pre-established
   RegEx that someone more experienced in this area might be familiar
   with.

Comment: Any idea what account numbers may look like??

Comment: So examples of patterns you'd like to match would be helpful. Have you made any attempts as yet? What went wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have an example set to reference.  So the problem I have is that I don't know what patterns to anticipate.  I am wondering if these are standardized for different carriers in a way similar to the way credit cards have standard, recognizable patterns?

Comment: I'm guessing you would have to figure out what to check for first then? Contact the shipping companies or try searching to see if you can figure out the format they use on their account #

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone~!  I'll try to contact the companies when I'm off the clock.  As for searching around, yes I tried that, but I've only encountered tracking number after tracking number.  Account numbers could be considered sensitive, so I suspect people are less forthcoming regarding these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are RegEx patterns to validate the accounts if the shipper is known. 
However, there are no RegEx patterns to determine the shipping company since they are of similar length with no other pattern to uniquely identify.

RegEx patterns:

UPS Small Package account - 6 digits

```
\d{6}
```

UPS Freight account 8 - digits

```
\d{8}
```

UPS Air Freight account 9 - digits

```
\d{9}
```

FEDEX – 9 digits

```
\d{9}
```

DHL – 9 digits

```
\d{9}
```

---

References:

From email with UPS customer support:
UPS Small Package account: 6 digits
UPS Freight account: 8 digits

Search "What is a UPS Account Number?" yields:
UPS Account Number or Shipper Number: 6 digits
Air Freight Account Number: 9 digits

Search "What is a FedEx Account Number?" yields:
9-digit FedEx account number for FedEx QuickShip

Search "how many digits in a dhl account number" yields:
Clues to an initial pattern of "170", "95, 96".

Internal shipping department has verified the patterns they use:
FEDEX  – 9 digits; UPS – 6 digits; DHL – 9 digits

Additional Research:
Email inquiries sent to UPS, FedEx, and DHL.
UPS has responded as indicated above.

Comment: As of 2018 our UPS Shipper Number is 6 characters including 2 letters - not just digits. I was hoping to find a pattern to validate against. UPS api docs don't include one, that i can find. My current solution is / will be to restrict to 6 characters.

Answer (score 2):

After a quick digging in Google:

FedEx Express code (old) <kbd>12 digits</kbd>:

```
\d{12}
```

FedEx Express code (new) <kbd>14 digits</kbd>:

```
\d{14}
```

FedEx Ground code (old) <kbd>15 digits</kbd>:

```
\d{15}
```

FedEx Ground code (new) <kbd>14 digits</kbd>:

```
\d{14}
```

UPS code <kbd>1Z9999999999999999</kbd>:

```
\d[A-Z]\d{16}
```

Comment: Big +1 for taking the time to actually look up the account codes (which I think the OP should've done).

Comment: Thanks for the RegEx's~!  Could I ask what Google-ing you performed to find these, or if you could direct me to some references?  My search results always resulted in Tracking Numbers and not Account Number patterns.  After my own investigation, my goal with going with the community was to see if there was a known standard that I could not locate myself.  Thanks, again, for the help~!  To Note: "Validate Shipper X Customer/Account Number" got me close, but seemed to hint at validating against the shipper systems, when I was hoping for a shallow validation against a pattern.

Comment: @kazebp You have to build your own patterns depending on the informations you can find. For example you can use http://www.onlinetrackingnumber.com/ - also try typing invalid codes in forms to check what errors they give. Maybe some of them will sot the pattern.

Comment: @hsz Thanks for the suggestion.  The challenge for me has been "the information I can find".  There is so much information regarding "Tracking Numbers", but I cannot seem to locate "Account Number" validation.  To clarify, this is the number the customer inputs to identify themselves to the shipper for billing purposes.  Because of the sensitive nature of account numbers, I believe that I will not find many sample values.  That's why I was hoping the community can help me determine the patterns (if they exist).